# Creating an array of a class inside of another class

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

This is a simplified version of a problem I am having. I'm trying to create an an array of ProduceItem inside of class database. I have outlined the warnings and problems I've encountered in my attempts. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //attempt 1: 
    //database a;
    // Warning: local variable a is not used.
    // Warning: Null pointer access: The variable a can only be null at this location

    //attempt 2:
    //database a;
    //a.test[0].setCode(2);
    //local variable has not been initialize

    //results in attempt 2 part 2
    //database a = null;
    //a.test[0].setCode(2);
    //Null pointer access: The variable a can only be null at this location
    //When I run it, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
    //at Test.main(Test.java:8) 
    //\which is a.test[0].setCode(1); 
    }
public class ProduceItem{
  private int code;
  public ProduceItem(){
     code = 0;
  }
  public int getCode(){
     return code;}

  public void setCode(int a){
     code = a;}
public class database{
  ProduceItem[] test;
  }
```

Comment: a = new database() ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try attempt #2 but first init database a.

```
Database a = new Database();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `ProduceItem` is an inner class of `Test` class and `database` is an inner class of `ProduceItem`. To create instances of inner classes you have to create an instance of the enclosing class.

Create a new `Test` object

```
Test test = new Test();
```

Create a new `ProduceItem` object

```
ProduceItem pItem = test.new ProduceItem();
```

Create a new `database` item

```
ProduceItem.database a = pItem.new database();
```

Then call methods for any of the elements of the array of `ProduceItem` inside `database`

```
a.test[0].setCode(2);
```

As as side note the convention in Java is that class names start with uppercase letters e.g. `Database`

More importantly your class hierarchy and the design with inner classes is little confusing and you may want to take a moment and think about it.

Comment: When I create a new database object `Database a = new Database();` I receive an error "No enclosing instance of type Test is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Test (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Test) @omer727

Comment: I notices that you have inner classes and changed my answer accordingly